# PYTHON : Nested loop from a dictionnary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested-loops

I Everyone,

I have a dictionary with a list of Dataframe Name as Key and URL as Value :

```
{'Season': '/api/DATA/SEASON',
 'Division': '/api/DATA/DIVISION',
 'Group': '/api/DATA/GROUP'}
```

And Dataframe with JSON inside

Season :

```
                                                  MSG
0   [{"seasonId":"PER","label":"Permanent","shortL...
1   [{"seasonId":"W08","label":"Hiver 08/09","shor...
2   [{"seasonId":"S09","label":"Eté 09","shortLabe...
3   [{"seasonId":"W09","label":"Hiver 09/10","shor...
4   [{"seasonId":"S10","label":"Eté 10","shortLabe...
```

Division :

```
                                                  MSG
0   [{"divisionId":1,"label":"THE KOOPLES","activi...
```

In order to send the right JSON to the right `UrlWS`, I need use the dictionnary Key to get data from the Dataframe :

```
for DataFrame,UrlWS from MappingDataWebservice.items() :
    for i in DataFrame.index :
        print(DataFrame.iloc[i][0]
```

But it's not working because the second loop doesn’t consider `DataFrame.index` as an iterable object.

If someone has a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
df
###
                                             MSG
0    [{'seasonId': 'PER', 'label': 'Permanent'}]
1  [{'seasonId': 'W08', 'label': 'Hiver 08/09'}]
2       [{'seasonId': 'S09', 'label': 'Eté 09'}]
3  [{'seasonId': 'W09', 'label': 'Hiver 09/10'}]
4       [{'seasonId': 'S10', 'label': 'Eté 10'}]
```

```
df['MSG'] = df['MSG'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df
###
                                           MSG
0    {'seasonId': 'PER', 'label': 'Permanent'}
1  {'seasonId': 'W08', 'label': 'Hiver 08/09'}
2       {'seasonId': 'S09', 'label': 'Eté 09'}
3  {'seasonId': 'W09', 'label': 'Hiver 09/10'}
4       {'seasonId': 'S10', 'label': 'Eté 10'}
```

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['MSG'])
df
###
  seasonId        label
0      PER    Permanent
1      W08  Hiver 08/09
2      S09       Eté 09
3      W09  Hiver 09/10
4      S10       Eté 10
```